# Unable to zip empty folder with Java in Ubuntu

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, zip

The project allows user to download a file which the downloaded file will be the zipped file. The downloaded zipped file works well except that the empty folder will not be included in the zipped folder. One of the developer implemented with the code below with his MacBook which doesn't trigger any error. However, when the source code is executed in ubuntu machine, error occurs.

The code:

```
def zipFolder(folderNamePath: String, subDirectory: String,zip: ZipOutputStream): Unit = {

    val file = new File(folderNamePath)
    val readBuffer = new Array[Byte](Buffer)
    val fileList = file.list()

    var i = 0
    for( i <- 0 until fileList.length ){
      val path = folderNamePath + "/" + fileList(i)
      val currFile = new File(path)
      if(currFile.isDirectory){
        val filePath = currFile.getPath
        zipFolder(filePath, subDirectory + '/' + fileList(i) ,zip)

      }else{
        val anEntry = new ZipEntry(subDirectory + '/' + fileList(i))
        val bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path), Buffer)
        zip.putNextEntry(anEntry)
        var bytesIn: Int = -1
        while({
          bytesIn = bis.read(readBuffer, 0, Buffer)
          bytesIn != -1
        }){
          zip.write(readBuffer, 0, bytesIn);
        }

        bis.close()
      }
    }

    //THE CODE BELOW IS TO ZIP EMPTY DIRECTORY
    if(fileList.length == 0){
      val path = folderNamePath
      val anEntry = new ZipEntry(subDirectory)
      val bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path + "/"), Buffer)
      zip.putNextEntry(anEntry)

      bis.close()
    }

  }
```

And the error logged:

```
! @75akh0a6a - Internal server error, for (POST) 
[/storage_ws/download_directory_file] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution 
exception[[FileNotFoundException: /home/jarvis/project/storage-api/media/jarvis/test/Test/Testing (Is a directory)]]
at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:146)
at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:145)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jarvis/project/storage-api/media/user/jarvis/Test/Testing (Is a directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at tools.ZipUtils$.zipFolder(ZipUtils.scala:122)
at tools.ZipUtils$$anonfun$zipFolder$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ZipUtils.scala:101)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
at tools.ZipUtils$.zipFolder(ZipUtils.scala:96)
at tools.IO$.handleDownloadDirectoryFile(IO.scala:176)
at controllers.FileHandleController$$anonfun$downloadDirectoryFile$1$$anonfun$apply$50.apply(FileHandleController.scala:586)
```

The code executed well without the following case `if(fileList.length == 0){` for zipping empty folder, which the zipped folder will exclude the empty folder.

Comment: Try to use FilenameUtils class from Apache Commons IO (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) or the Paths class from java.nio (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html). 
There are bunch of useful methods. Always helped me when in trouble with cross-platform developing. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because you are trying to open a FileInputStream on a directory instead of a file.

Indeed, you see the exception message here:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jarvis/project/storage-api/media/user/jarvis/Test/Testing (Is a directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

Here you are with a slightly modified version of your method that should solve the problem. Please note that I replaced all the '/' occurrences with File.separator instead.

```
def zipFolder(folderNamePath: String, subDirectory: String,zip: ZipOutputStream): Unit = {

    val file = new File(folderNamePath)
    val readBuffer = new Array[Byte](Buffer)
    val fileList = file.list()

    var i = 0
    for( i <- 0 until fileList.length ){
      val currFile = new File(folderNamePath, fileList(i))
      if(currFile.isDirectory){
        val filePath = currFile.getPath
        zipFolder(filePath, subDirectory + File.separator + fileList(i) ,zip)

      }else{
        val path = folderNamePath + File.separator + fileList(i)
        val anEntry = new ZipEntry(subDirectory + File.separator + fileList(i))
        val bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path), Buffer)
        zip.putNextEntry(anEntry)
        var bytesIn: Int = -1
        while({
          bytesIn = bis.read(readBuffer, 0, Buffer)
          bytesIn != -1
        }){
          zip.write(readBuffer, 0, bytesIn);
        }

        bis.close()
      }
    }

    //THE CODE BELOW IS TO ZIP EMPTY DIRECTORY
    if(fileList.length == 0){
      zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(subDirectory + File.separator))
      zip.closeEntry()
    }
}
```

The empty folder will only be visible when the zipped file is extracted. *At least, for Ubuntu default zip tool(Archive Manage)*

Comment: The code above works! However there is a flaw there which the empty folder become an unknown file. Any idea?

Comment: I added "/" into zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(subDirectory + "/")). The empty folder is gone again

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: How do you solve the empty folder becoming unknown file after zip? Add a "/" at the end doesn't help =(

Comment: Try to use: zip.closeEntry(); after the zip.putNextEntry call. See my edit above.

Comment: what about this? zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(subDirectory + File.separator + "."))

Comment: The empty folder will have a file name "." inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154305/discussion-between-p3trur0-and-mervyn-lee).